# Returning on conditional if from inside Array.filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to return the index of an item that meets a certain condition from within an `Array.filter` method, but I still keep getting an array of actual values instead of the **indexes** of the values I want.

Example:

```
var seq = [3, 4, 1, 2, 1];

seq.filter((curr, index) => {
  if (seq[index + 1] < seq[index]) {
    return index;
  }
});

// returns [4, 2]
// want to return [1, 3] (the indexes of 4 & 2)
```

Is there a more efficient method I can use? I'm trying to avoid using a for loop. Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: filter cb returns are interpreted as boolean.

Comment: [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) *expects* you to return either `true` for `false` from the callback.  This tells it whether to keep that value or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` here

```js
var seq = [3, 4, 1, 2, 1];

var result = seq.reduce((ar, curr, index) => {
  if (seq[index + 1] < seq[index]) ar.push(index);
  return ar;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wondering how you fed `ar` as the first argument into reduce? MDN shows `previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array`. I want to use the `previous` parameter that the reduce method comes with, but whenever I include it (with the parameters in the current order you have shown) it breaks.

Comment: Well i added `[]` at end as optional parameter so now `previousValue` is `initialValue` or `ar` in this case.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into adjusting that, because it won't return the last item in a given array due to there being no "next" value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter with an array of the indices and the right test for the return

```js
var seq = [3, 4, 1, 2, 1],
    result = seq.map(function (_, i) { return i; }).filter(function (i) {
        return seq[i - 1] < seq[i];
    });

console.log(result);
```

The better solution would be a loop with forEach

```js
var seq = [3, 4, 1, 2, 1],
    result = [];

seq.forEach(function (a, i) {
    seq[i - 1] < a && this.push(i);
}, result);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad idea to use a for loop in this case. I personally think it's cleaner and more efficient.

```
let seq = [3, 4, 1, 2, 1];
for (let i = 0; i < seq.length; i++) {
  if (seq[i + 1] < seq[i]) {
    continue;
  }
  seq.splice(i, 1);
}
```